# Why is this code working

Tags: xor

I was doing some introductory challenges at CryptoHack and one of the challenges, more precisely it was [Favourite Byte](https://cryptohack.org/courses/intro/xorkey0/), XOR with a single byte.

I did my solution with XORing given string and single key iterated over 256 integers till I  find something that looks like "flag".

Then I looked for submitted solutions and one of the solutions was:

```
input_str = bytes.fromhex('73626960647f6b206821204f21254f7d694f7624662065622127234f726927756d')

key = input_str[0] ^ ord('c')
print(''.join(chr(c ^ key) for c in input_str))
```

The part that is giving me trouble is the third line or assignment of the `key` variable. Why is this key working? In other words, how did he find it? My best guess is he did exactly what I did earlier(iterated over 256 integers) and once he found it he modified his code.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: They did find it on their computer and only submitted this. It is CryptoHack's problem that they accept this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing very difficult going on here.

As the website says, its flags are usually in the format [crypto{y0ur_f1rst_fl4g}](https://cryptohack.org/challenges/introduction/). It's thus very likely that the first character of the flag you're trying to retrieve is `c`, which means that the XOR key must be the ASCII value of `c` (0x63) XORed with the first character of the ciphertext (0x73).